# Entity Framework Core, what is the best way to run sql after DB is generating

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

i want run some code for triggers and other changes

is there an event to register?, something like `OnDbCreate`

Answer (score 1):

If you want do some changes, you can use Up Method in your recently added Migration. Anything you change there, will be applied in the Database after you call Update-Database from Package Manager Console. You can even run custom Sql Query if you want.